# Admin files, downloadable in front end

Tags: channel-entries

I am busy with a site which should allow authenticated users to upload and download files, however am having issues.

Firstly i created custom channel fields, which allow file uploads. the image file upload works, the audio upload field also works but when i try upload a video it gives an error the video file 1.1MB.

Am i missing a step?

Comment: What error? What kind of file is the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check what is your max upload limit (post_max_size) in the php.ini file. Changes this to a larger amount will allow for bigger file upload. Also check memory_limit (Maximum amount of memory a script may consume).